# Let $X$ be an ordered set. If $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$ that is convex in $X$, then is $Y$ an interval or ray in $X$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

The question is from Munkres and this has been answered a lot of time. However, the problems that I am facing are:

1. How does a ray look like in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?
2. What is an interval in an arbitrary topological space $X$?
3. How do I think and find out an example that does not satisfy the question ?(I don't want an answer to this question but a hint so that I can find my own answer.)

An example: Consider the dictionary topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the convex set $S=\{x^2+y^2<1\}$.We see that this set $S$ is convex. I am not sure whether it is an interval or ray? What is it?

Comment: From the context given, I assume the words convex, interval, and ray are all properties of a subset of a (totally) ordered set. This question does not (directly) concern topological spaces at all.

Comment: This question is from munkres - topology ,Okay, I'll chnage the tags.

Comment: When you talk about a ray (in the context of ordered sets), perhaps you should mention what is the order you're using on $\Bbb R^n$. Are you using the dictionary order?

Comment: As for your second question, there is no notion of an interval in an arbitrary topological space $X$. Maybe you are confusing it with the order topology that Munkres defines. However, there you start with an ordered set and then put a topology on it. Not all topologies arise in this way. Indeed, consider the indiscrete topology on any two points set.

Comment: Order is not mentioned in the question itself.This from Munkres chapter section-16 (Q-7).I don't understand , how is an interval defined with respect to an order different from the interval itself.I am reading topology for the first time,I am sorry if it is something that I should know

Comment: @Antimony I think you may go through the Munkres (sec 14 - The order topology) for the basic definition that how intervals and rays are defined in any Topological Space wrt. the simple order relation, then from the Theorem 16.4 you will get the idea that how Y will look like in X, lastly from the definition of convexity you may sketch your answer.

Comment: This post doesn't make much sense. Your title asks a question about an ordered set $X$. But the body of your post is not about an ordered set, it is instead about certain subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ and of $\mathbb R^3$ and of arbitrary topological spaces.

Comment: These are the questions that I had when I was trying to solve the problem.I am not sure how else should I be framing the question.Do you think the example I have come up with is a valid contradictory example to the question ?

Comment: @LeeMosher: I think the idea is this: (1) we have a theorem about ordered sets; we also have definitions (presumably) of "interval" and "ray" in an arbitrary ordered set; (2) the plane and 3-space can be considered as ordered sets using the lexicographic order; (3) OP wonders what intervals and rays in the plane, using this order, look like. OP also conjectures that the open unit disk in the usual metric is in fact "convex" in the lexicographic order, which doesn't seem clear to me, but asks "if it IS convex, then is it an *interval* or a *ray* within the lexicographic order?"

Answer (score 1):

I think that your confusion may arise from the notion of "convex" --- things aren't just 'convex', they're convex with respect to some notion of "interval" (often a vector-space structure) or with respect to some order.

Anyhow, let me answer your question about the lexicographic order on the plane, where $(a, b) < (p, q)$ if $b < q$ or if $b = q$ and $a < p$, which I write out just to fix the order. (Your text may use the opposite convention, but this is the one I am using. If your text uses the other, just swap the first an second coordinate in every interval below.)

The "increasing ray" from a point $(a, b)$ consists of all points $(x, b)$ where $x \ge a$, together with all points $(x, y)$ where $y > b$. In other words, it's the open half-plane above level $b$,together with the half-line to the right of $(a, b)$.

The intersection of two such rays constitutes an interval.

Now let's look at the unit disk, $D$, which is "convex" as a subset of the 2-dimensional vector-space $\Bbb R^2$, and see whether it's convex with respect to the lexicographic order.

Well, the points $(0,0)$ and $(0, .5)$ are both in $D$, so if $D$ is convex, it must contain every point $(x, y)$ between these two. But let's look at the point $P = (100, 0)$. This point is greater than $(0,0)$ in the lexicographic order, but less than $(0, 0.5)$ in that order, so if $D$ were convex, then the point $P$ would have to be in there. But because $100^2 + 0^2 \ge 1$, $P$ is not in $D$.

So your assumption that $D$ is convex (in the order) is mistaken.